# Component Symbol identification; 2-pin rectangle with an N

Tags: diodes, components, identification, esd

I couldn't find anything on the web for it.

On first thought it might be an ESD protection diode because in the schematic, t appears near USB and stuff that might be sensitive.

[image], here in context :

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Maybe ? Not sure about it too

Comment: Maybe https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/237442/6383

Answer (score 2):

Looks like these are **PESD (Polymer ESD) devices**, like in this schematic:
[image]

Here is a [datasheet](http://m.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/polymer_esd_suppressors/littelfuse_polymer_esd_suppressor_pesd_catalog_datasheet.pdf.pdf) of one of these.

The schematic and explanation can be found [here](https://www.ecnmag.com/article/2009/12/circuit-protection-considerations-usb-30).